# Fetch the first image url of a blogger post when it is not hosted on Blogger for related posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

I am using a hosting service where I store the images I put on blogger.

The problem is blogger doesn't seem to fetch the image url to be the thumbnail of the when it's not uploaded/hosted on blogger.

How can I make those external images appear on those thumbnails??

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
// JS LQ
var defaultnoimage = "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_u4gySN2ZgqE/SosvnavWq0I/AAAAAAAAArk/yL95WlyTqr0/s400/noimage.png";
var maxresults = 8;
var splittercolor = "#d4eaf2";
var relatedpoststitle = "YOU MIGHT WANT TO SEE";
var relatedTitles = new Array();
var relatedTitlesNum = 0;
var relatedUrls = new Array();
var thumburl = new Array();

function related_results_labels_thumbs(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
        var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
        relatedTitles[relatedTitlesNum] = entry.title.$t;
        try {
            thumburl[relatedTitlesNum] = entry.media$thumbnail.url
        } catch (error) {
            s = entry.content.$t;
            a = s.indexOf("<img");
            b = s.indexOf("src=\"", a);
            c = s.indexOf("\"", b + 5);
            d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5);
            if ((a != -1) && (b != -1) && (c != -1) && (d != "")) {
                thumburl[relatedTitlesNum] = d
            } else {
                if (typeof(defaultnoimage) !== 'undefined') {
                    thumburl[relatedTitlesNum] = defaultnoimage
                } else {
                    thumburl[relatedTitlesNum] = "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_u4gySN2ZgqE/SosvnavWq0I/AAAAAAAAArk/yL95WlyTqr0/s400/noimage.png"
                }
            }
        }
        if (relatedTitles[relatedTitlesNum].length > 35) {
            relatedTitles[relatedTitlesNum] = relatedTitles[relatedTitlesNum].substring(0, 150) + "..."
        }
        for (var k = 0; k < entry.link.length; k++) {
            if (entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') {
                relatedUrls[relatedTitlesNum] = entry.link[k].href;
                relatedTitlesNum++
            }
        }
    }
}

function removeRelatedDuplicates_thumbs() {
    var tmp = new Array(0);
    var tmp2 = new Array(0);
    var tmp3 = new Array(0);
    for (var i = 0; i < relatedUrls.length; i++) {
        if (!contains_thumbs(tmp, relatedUrls[i])) {
            tmp.length += 1;
            tmp[tmp.length - 1] = relatedUrls[i];
            tmp2.length += 1;
            tmp3.length += 1;
            tmp2[tmp2.length - 1] = relatedTitles[i];
            tmp3[tmp3.length - 1] = thumburl[i]
        }
    }
    relatedTitles = tmp2;
    relatedUrls = tmp;
    thumburl = tmp3
}

function contains_thumbs(a, e) {
    for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        if (a[j] == e) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

function printRelatedLabels_thumbs(current) {
    var splitbarcolor;
    if (typeof(splittercolor) !== 'undefined') {
        splitbarcolor = splittercolor
    } else {
        splitbarcolor = "#d4eaf2"
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < relatedUrls.length; i++) {
        if ((relatedUrls[i] == current) || (!relatedTitles[i])) {
            relatedUrls.splice(i, 1);
            relatedTitles.splice(i, 1);
            thumburl.splice(i, 1);
            i--
        }
    }
    var r = Math.floor((relatedTitles.length - 1) * Math.random());
    var i = 0;
    if (relatedTitles.length > 0) {
        document.write('<div class="phimlq"><i class="lq"></i>' + relatedpoststitle + '</div>')
    }
    document.write('<div style="clear: both;"/>');
    while (i < relatedTitles.length && i < 20 && i < maxresults) {
        document.write('<a href="' + relatedUrls[r] + '"><div class="popular-row"><div class="in-article"><div class="wrap-photos"><img class="ppl-img" src="' + thumburl[r].replace("/s72-c/", "/s200/") + '"/></div><h3 name="title">' + relatedTitles[r] + ']</h3><span class="icon-hover"></span><div class="br"></div></div></div></a>');
        i++;
        if (r < relatedTitles.length - 1) {
            r++
        } else {
            r = 0
        }
    }
    document.write('</div>');
    relatedUrls.splice(0, relatedUrls.length);
    thumburl.splice(0, thumburl.length);
    relatedTitles.splice(0, relatedTitles.length)
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get image src directly from `entry.content` instead of `media$thumbnail`

**Try this**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
// JS LQ
var defaultnoimage = "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_u4gySN2ZgqE/SosvnavWq0I/AAAAAAAAArk/yL95WlyTqr0/s400/noimage.png";
var maxresults = 8;
var splittercolor = "#d4eaf2";
var relatedpoststitle = "YOU MIGHT WANT TO SEE";
var relatedTitles = new Array();
var relatedTitlesNum = 0;
var relatedUrls = new Array();
var thumburl = new Array();

function related_results_labels_thumbs(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
        var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
        relatedTitles[relatedTitlesNum] = entry.title.$t;
        s = entry.content.$t;
        a = s.indexOf("<img");
        b = s.indexOf("src=\", a);
        c = s.indexOf("\", b + 5);
        d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5);
        if ((a != -1) && (b != -1) && (c != -1) && (d != "")) {
            thumburl[relatedTitlesNum] = d;
        } else {
            if (typeof(defaultnoimage) !== 'undefined') {
                thumburl[relatedTitlesNum] = defaultnoimage;
            } else {
                thumburl[relatedTitlesNum] = "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_u4gySN2ZgqE/SosvnavWq0I/AAAAAAAAArk/yL95WlyTqr0/s400/noimage.png";
            }
        }
        if (relatedTitles[relatedTitlesNum].length > 35) {
            relatedTitles[relatedTitlesNum] = relatedTitles[relatedTitlesNum].substring(0, 150) + "...";
        }
        for (var k = 0; k < entry.link.length; k++) {
            if (entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') {
                relatedUrls[relatedTitlesNum] = entry.link[k].href;
                relatedTitlesNum++;
            }
        }
    }
}

function removeRelatedDuplicates_thumbs() {
    var tmp = new Array(0);
    var tmp2 = new Array(0);
    var tmp3 = new Array(0);
    for (var i = 0; i < relatedUrls.length; i++) {
        if (!contains_thumbs(tmp, relatedUrls[i])) {
            tmp.length += 1;
            tmp[tmp.length - 1] = relatedUrls[i];
            tmp2.length += 1;
            tmp3.length += 1;
            tmp2[tmp2.length - 1] = relatedTitles[i];
            tmp3[tmp3.length - 1] = thumburl[i];
        }
    }
    relatedTitles = tmp2;
    relatedUrls = tmp;
    thumburl = tmp3;
}

function contains_thumbs(a, e) {
    for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        if (a[j] == e) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function printRelatedLabels_thumbs(current) {
    var splitbarcolor;
    if (typeof(splittercolor) !== 'undefined') {
        splitbarcolor = splittercolor;
    } else {
        splitbarcolor = "#d4eaf2";
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < relatedUrls.length; i++) {
        if ((relatedUrls[i] == current) || (!relatedTitles[i])) {
            relatedUrls.splice(i, 1);
            relatedTitles.splice(i, 1);
            thumburl.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    var r = Math.floor((relatedTitles.length - 1) * Math.random());
    var i = 0;
    if (relatedTitles.length > 0) {
        document.write('<div class="phimlq"><i class="lq"></i>' + relatedpoststitle + '</div>');
    }
    document.write('<div style="clear: both;"/>');
    while (i < relatedTitles.length && i < 20 && i < maxresults) {
        document.write('<a href="' + relatedUrls[r] + '"><div class="popular-row"><div class="in-article"><div class="wrap-photos"><img class="ppl-img" src="' + thumburl[r].replace("/s72-c/", "/s200/") + '"/></div><h3 name="title">' + relatedTitles[r] + ']</h3><span class="icon-hover"></span><div class="br"></div></div></div></a>');
        i++;
        if (r < relatedTitles.length - 1) {
            r++;
        } else {
            r = 0;
        }
    }
    document.write('</div>');
    relatedUrls.splice(0, relatedUrls.length);
    thumburl.splice(0, thumburl.length);
    relatedTitles.splice(0, relatedTitles.length);
}
//]]>
</script>
```